# Filter elements : current date is between element 'startdate' and 'enddate'?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some xml file. Inside this xml file there are alot of "vacature" elements. I would like to filter these "vacature" elements to show only the actual ones.

Here is an example of my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitegegevens>
<vacatures>

<vacature id="27223" >
 <titel>TitelA</titel>
 <startdate>16-05-2014</startdate>
 <enddate>11-08-2014</enddate>
</vacature>

<vacature id="27224" >
 <titel>TitelB</titel>
 <startdate>16-05-2014</startdate>
 <enddate>11-06-2014</enddate>
</vacature>

<vacature id="27225" >
 <titel>TitelC</titel>
 <startdate>16-09-2014</startdate>
 <enddate>11-10-2014</enddate>
</vacature>

</vacatures>
</sitegegevens>
```

And this is my current xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:template match="vacature">

<h1><xsl:value-of select="titel"/></h1> <br/>

Start date: <xsl:value-of select="startdate"/><br/>
End date: <xsl:value-of select="enddate"/><br/>

<br/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current xsl shows 3x the vacature elements. I would like to show only the vacature elements which are actual. Some filter like this:

> current date is between "startdate" and "enddate"

This is the html output wich I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><h1 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">TitelA</h1>
<br xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" />
Start date: 16-05-2014<br xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" />
End date: 11-08-2014<br xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" />
```

Like you see there is only 1 of the 3 "vacature" elements filtered because the current date is between the startdate and the enddate.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact output XML (HTML?) you would like to get.

Comment: There is no current-date function in XSLT 1.0. If your processor supports it, you can use the EXSLT date() or date-time() extension function. If not, you will have to pass the current date as a parameter to the stylesheet at runtime, or get the date from a web service.

Comment: Please give me an example of how to get the current date. The example of "Mathias Muller" doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you would like to achieve, but as I understand you are trying to compare dates in XSLT 1.0.

The stylesheet below does not yield exactly the result you have shown, because it does not seem to make sense (it is incomplete HTML on the one hand, and cluttered with surplus namespaces on the other). But it singles out the one `vacature` element where your condition is true.

The method is this: Create a variable for the current date ( which is not immediately available in XSLT 1.0, you need an extension function like EXSLT). Then, convert the content of the `startdate` and `enddate` elements from your XML input into a format that allows comparisons, that is, *YYYYMMDD* in this case.

Finally, an `xsl:if` element tests whether the start date is "less" and the end date is "greater" than the current date.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="date">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="current-date" select="translate(substring-before(date:date-time(), 'T'), '-', '')"/>

    <xsl:template match="vacature">

        <xsl:variable name="start-date" select="concat(substring(startdate, 7),substring(startdate,4,2), substring(startdate,1,2))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end-date" select="concat(substring(enddate, 7),substring(enddate,4,2), substring(enddate,1,2))"/>

        <xsl:if test="$start-date &lt; $current-date and $end-date &gt; $current-date">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vacature id="27223">
   <titel>TitelA</titel>
   <startdate>16-05-2014</startdate>
   <enddate>11-08-2014</enddate>
</vacature>
```

---

As you can see, the variable definition for `$current-date` is a top-level element outside the template that matches `vacature` elements. If the template is invoked several times on different dates, this might distort the results.

Comment: I started with adding the current date in my xslt: Current date: <xsl:variable name="current-date" select="translate(substring-before(date:date-time(), 'T'), '-', '')"/> but the xsl is not valid any more. The xml is like above, I didnt change it. What is wrong?

Comment: First of all, _never_ post code in comments. Edit your post instead. Second, "not valid anymore" is very unhelpful. What's the error message, what's wrong?

Comment: This is the error: Failed to apply XSLT to the content. I am using the "XML viewer" Webpart in SharePoint.

Comment: There is no way I can help you with that. You did show us neither a complete XSLT stylesheet nor a complete output file.

Comment: I figured out I can only use xslt 1.0. Please help, how to filter filter elements on date?

Comment: I have shown you exactly that. In what way did I not answer your question?

Comment: @hakh Try applying the suggested stylesheet **as-is**, without making any changes to it - and without pasting parts of it into your own stylesheet. Then if you get an error message, please reproduce it here fully and exactly.

Comment: Michael, I try the stylesheet as-is. It didnt work. I got this error: Failed to apply XSLT to the content.

Comment: @user1326231 There is nothing wrong with the XSLT code I provided. If you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor, have access to the EXSLT extension functions and if you faithfully copied my stylesheet, it works. (That is, if you also know how to handle your XSLT processor and how to apply a stylesheet and source XML)